# How to execute update for multiple rows by linq expression as a where clause

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We use some sort of criteria language to pass queries' where clauses from clients to server. When it comes to server we convert it to linq expression and execute query with NH.
For example 'get events page' query seems like that:

```
Session.Query<EventExtractData>()
.Where(message.Criteria.GetExpression())
.OrderByDescending(e => e.CreateTimeUtc)
.Skip(message.Start)
.Take(message.Size)
.ToArray()
```

message.Criteria is a composition of "atomic" criterions implementing abstract Criterion<T> and glued with And<T> and Or<T> criterions. Each concrete criterion implements Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression()  function.
It's work.
Now we want to use same criterions to execute updates on multiple rows.
I can't just fetch all rows that comply for the criteria and then update them one by one. It will be a performance issue. 
I want to execute update by one single command:

```
UPDATE <real view name of mapped EventExtractData class> 
SET <my business logic> 
WHERE <my criterions' linq expression translated to SQL where clause>
```

I am looking for a way to implement this update with NH.
Actualy, I think what I need is to parse linq expression to sql with NH linq provider.
How to do it?

---------------------------------- Update --------------------------
There are some intermideate results of drilling into NH internals:

```
var implementor = session.GetSessionImplementation();
var hqlUpdate = "update EventExtractData e set e.Status = 2, e.CloseReason = 'Multiple close', e.ClosedUTC = :now";
var updatePlan = new HQLStringQueryPlan(hqlUpdate, false, implementor.EnabledFilters, implementor.Factory);
string sqlUpdate = updatePlan.SqlStrings[0];
```

and this giving me following sql expression:

> update EV_EventData_VW set Status=2, CloseReason='Multiple close',
>   ClosedUTC=?

Now I will simulate select query and get it's sql expression

```
var dummyQuery = session.Query<EventExtractData>().Where(message.Criteria.GetExpression());
var nhQuery = new NhLinqExpression(dummyQuery.Expression);
var selectPlan = new HQLExpressionQueryPlan(nhQuery.Key, nhQuery, false, implementor.EnabledFilters, implementor.Factory);
string sqlSelect = selectPlan.SqlStrings[0];
```

and this giving me:

> select 
>    eventextra0_.ID as ID31_, 
>   eventextra0_.NaturalID as
>   NaturalID31_, 
>     eventextra0_.Site as Site31_, 
>     eventextra0_.CreateTimeUTC as CreateTi4_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.Description as Descript5_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.EventTypeDisplayName as EventTyp6_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.Severity as Severity31_, 
>   eventextra0_.Status as
>   Status31_, 
>    eventextra0_.CreateUser as CreateUser31_, 
>     eventextra0_.Owner as Owner31_, 
>     eventextra0_.CloseUser as
>   CloseUser31_, 
>     eventextra0_.ExceededUTC as Exceede12_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.ExpiredUTC as ExpiredUTC31_, 
>     eventextra0_.ClosedUTC as ClosedUTC31_, 
>     eventextra0_.OwnedUTC
>   as OwnedUTC31_, 
>   eventextra0_.IsFalseEvent as IsFalse16_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.CloseReason as CloseRe17_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.IsCloseCommentMandatory as IsClose18_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.PossibleTrueCloseReasons as Possibl19_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.PossibleFalseCloseReasons as Possibl20_31_, 
>     eventextra0_.IsExpired as IsExpired31_, 
>     eventextra0_.IsExceeded
>   as IsExceeded31_, 
>     eventextra0_.SourceElementID as SourceE23_31_,
>   
>   eventextra0_.SourceElementDisplayName as SourceE24_31_ 
>  from
>   EV_EventData_VW eventextra0_ 
>  where eventextra0_.IsExpired=1 and
>   eventextra0_.ExpiredUTC<?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DML style operations, but you will have to [resort to HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct).

However, if you feel the need to query with LINQ, I would fetch the corresponding IDs which should be a very lightweight query and then use HQL with those:

```
var ids = Session.Query<EventExtractData>()
         .Where(message.Criteria.GetExpression())
         .Select(x=>x.Id)
         .ToList();

int count = Session.CreateQuery(@"update EventExtractData evt
                                  set evt.Date =:date 
                                  where evt.Id in (:ids)")
           .SetParameter("date", DateTime.Now)
           .SetParameterList("ids", ids)
           .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Its a table with a several milions of rows. In a worst scenario user will want to update all rows. So I can't fetch event's ids. And yes, we warned a client about an issue but he still want ability to update multiple rows by choosing criteria and single click.

Comment: @StanB in that case, as far as I know, you can't perform DML-style operations using LINQ. I have a similar case at work and I -sadly- have to build up an HQL query using StringBuilder.